# Import datatables

Tags: angular, datatable, datatables, cdn

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,700,700i,600,600i">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/bs-animation.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/smoothproducts.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/theme.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
```

Despite I have imported DataTable in my index.html (I'm using angular 8 but I prefer to import it locally) and I have this script:

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

this is my html:

```
<table class="table dataTable my-0" id="dataTableUser"></table>
```

and this is my script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dataTableUser').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: Why using DataTables with Angular? It is a lot easier to work on other Angular DataTables instead of the jQuery one. You can check NgPrime table, Angular Material table and many more

Comment: @yazantahhan I don't know this tables, can you please link me some guides?

Comment: NgPrime: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview NgxDatatable https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with `@yazantahhan`, JQuery and Angular normally lead to issues later in the project when you are using it to manipulate the DOM.

But to solve your issue, you most likely just need `declare var $ : any;` at the top of your `.ts`.

I use [MatTables](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) instead of dataTables.

Comment: I have declared var $ : any; but I still get the same error

Comment: @Francesco to clarify... `declare var $ : any;`  as seen here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html not just declaring a `var $` ;)